# Extra curly braket in JSON & Parsing

Tags: php, android, json, restful-architecture

I'm using rest ful service and it adds extra auto-numbered curly brackets as shown:

```
    {
  "budgets": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "balance": "0",
      "addedBy": "Jhon",
      "NameBD": "Camping",
      "limitBD": "0",
      "DateBD": "2013-11-16 04:34:03"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "balance": "0",
      "addedBy": "Aziz",
      "NameBD": "My Home",
      "limitBD": "0",
      "DateBD": "2013-11-16 10:33:11"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "balance": "0",
      "addedBy": "Ryd",
      "NameBD": "My Department",


       "limitBD": "0",
          "DateBD": "2013-10-24 17:40:43"
        }
    ]
  }
```

and when i try to parse them it shows no value in "budgets"
so i tried to view them in JSON Viewer:

[image]

here is my PHP function inside rest controller:

```
public function allbudget_get()
    {
        $data = $this->db->get('budget');
        $this->response( array('budgets'=>$data->result()) , 200);
    }
```

is there any way to remove them?

**UPDATE**: the app code is:

```
private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Locate the Class 
            bd = new ArrayList<AllBudgets>();
            // Create an array to populate the spinner 
            bdlist = new ArrayList<String>();
            // JSON file URL address
            jsonobject = JSONfunctions
                    .getJSONfromURL("http://localhost/SharedBudget/index.php/Budget/allbudget");

            try {
                // Locate the NodeList name
                jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("budgets");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

                    AllBudgets bdget = new AllBudgets();

                    bdget.setId(jsonobject.optString("id"));
                    bdget.setAddedBy(jsonobject.optString("addedBy"));
                    bdget.setNameBD(jsonobject.optString("NameBD"));
                    bdget.setDateBD(jsonobject.optString("DateBD"));
                    bdget.add(bdget);

                    // Populate spinner with budget names
                    bdlist.add(jsonobject.optString("NameBD"));

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Here is the JSON code for parsing

public class JSONfunctions {

```
    public static JSONObject getJSONfromURL(String url) {
        InputStream is = null;
        String result = "";
        JSONObject jArray = null;

        // Download JSON data from URL
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }

        // Convert response to string
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        try {

            jArray = new JSONObject(result);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        return jArray;
    }
}
```

***UPDATE LOGCAT***
i also have setters & getters but i know they aren't the issue herethe logcat shows:

```
11-18 21:32:39.680: D/InputTransport(27646): Input channel constructed: name='ClientState{43f51ee0 uid 10152 pid 27646} (server)', fd=59
11-18 21:32:40.760: E/Error(27646): No value for budgets
11-18 21:32:40.760: W/System.err(27646): org.json.JSONException: No value for budgets
11-18 21:32:40.765: W/System.err(27646):    at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
11-18 21:32:40.765: W/System.err(27646):    at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:548)
11-18 21:32:40.765: W/System.err(27646):    at com.androidbegin.jsonspinnertutorial.MainActivity$DownloadJSON.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:49)
11-18 21:32:40.765: W/System.err(27646):    at com.androidbegin.jsonspinnertutorial.MainActivity$DownloadJSON.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
11-18 21:32:40.765: W/System.err(27646):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
11-18 21:32:40.765: W/System.err(27646):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
11-18 21:32:40.765: W/System.err(27646):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
11-18 21:32:40.765: W/System.err(27646):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
11-18 21:32:40.765: W/System.err(27646):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
11-18 21:32:40.765: W/System.err(27646):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
11-18 21:32:41.230: D/dalvikvm(27646): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 214K, 16% free 10193K/12064K, paused 20ms, total 21ms
11-18 21:32:41.230: I/dalvikvm-heap(27646): Grow heap (frag case) to 12.641MB for 1127536-byte allocation
11-18 21:32:41.255: D/dalvikvm(27646): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 15% free 11294K/13168K, paused 22ms, total 22ms
11-18 21:32:41.265: D/AbsListView(27646): Get MotionRecognitionManager
11-18 21:32:41.275: D/InputTransport(27646): Input channel constructed: name='44913558 PopupWindow:42738418 (client)', fd=56
11-18 21:32:41.300: D/AbsListView(27646): unregisterIRListener() is called 
11-18 21:32:41.305: D/AbsListView(27646): unregisterIRListener() is called 
11-18 21:32:41.310: D/AbsListView(27646): unregisterIRListener() is called 
11-18 21:33:18.115: D/AbsListView(27646): unregisterIRListener() is called
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You have an object with an element `budgets`, which is an array of objects. So what is the problem?

Comment: **"when i try to parse them it shows no value in "budgets" "** Show the code you're using to parse it. As Machavity says the JSON you've posted is a JSON object with a single key/value. The key is budgets and the value is a JSON array. Each array element is a JSON object with 6 keys/values.

Comment: @Squonk i posted the code

Comment: @Machavity Yeah under the array of objects **budgets** there is a number for each object, i'm not sure but i think those numbers don't matter even tho i'm still getting the 'No value for budgets' error.

Comment: @user2980953 : Your InputStreamReader is using iso-8859-1 encoding. Have you tried using UTF-8 instead?

Comment: @Squonk i just added the LogCat it's still the same

Comment: @user2980953 : Are you absolutely sure the result you get is the same as that JSON you show at the start of your question? Have you tried logging it and verifying that the result String is valid JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, i used httpPost while the function uses GET so i just replaced it:

```
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
```

Thanks to all of you who tried to help!